# Enforce live validation on an input edit

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

**Some background,** I'm using a directive to enforce live validation of a currency input field. I do this by defining a regex `pattern`, listening for `keypress` events on an input field, and using `pattern.test()` with the user's input as the parameter to the function. If my function does not find a match with `pattern.test()`, I use `preventDefault()` on the keypress event to block the digit from entering into the input. Thus, only digits that match my `pattern` are allowed into the input. This all works perfectly fine in the use scenario that the user does not want to go back and edit his/her input. See code below.

```
var pattern = new RegExp('^\\-{0,1}[0-9]{0,}\\.{0,1}[0-9]{0,2}$');

element.on('keypress', function(event) {
   var testString = element[0].value + event.key;
   if (!pattern.test(testString)) {
     event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

**The issue** I have is when I want to edit the user input after it has passed validation. To clarify, the way I have written the code, the regex tests against `var testString = element[0].value + event.key`, and has no knowledge of positional changes.

So, if 123.45 was currently in the input box, when I want to edit it to 6123.45, my regex is actually testing against 123.456 instead (because the `event.key` is always appended to the end of the current value in the input box). Since my regex only allows 2 decimal places, the new key gets `preventDefault()` called on it - making it seem like an edit to the value is invalid.

I can't seem to reliably get the LIVE value in the input box while still focused in it (have tried `ctrl.$viewValue` and `ctrl.$modelValue` as well, but this always ends up being the value BEFORE the new key I have just entered).

Does anyone have any suggestions on how I could go about enforcing this live validation and supporting edits?

Comment: You should take a look at [ngPattern](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngPattern)

Comment: @Titus this was actually what I used initially, but it wasn't playing nicely with the regex I use. I'll give it another try and see if it works out any better.

Comment: If that doesn't work, try to use `keyup` instead of `keypress`. I think that when `keyup` is fired the model will contain the final value.

Comment: This is true, but you can't call `preventDefault` on a `keyup` event because it fires after the default action.